# Get geometry of Line Callout using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, annotation

How can I extract the geometry of a line callout and the border of an annotation featureclass in ArcGIS desktop. I want to transfert those to a separate featureclass.

I'm able to get the Anchor point of the callout, but it's not enough for my needs.

I have try to use following code, but it doesn't return nothing. In the code, I try to get a polyline, but I've also try to get a polygon with the same results. I'm using ArcMap version 9.3 but I also tried with 10 and I have same results. Quite strange also that the method QueryBoundary on IQueryGeometry says at run-time that it's not implemented!

```vb
Dim pActiveView As IActiveView = pMap
Dim pScreenDisplay As IScreenDisplay = pActiveView.ScreenDisplay
Dim pDisplayTransform As IDisplayTransformation = pScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation

Dim pFDOGraphicsLayer As IFDOGraphicsLayer = pMap.Layer(0)   'The Annotation featureclass
Dim pFDOGraphicsLayerRead As IFDOGraphicsLayerRead = pFDOGraphicsLayer

pFDOGraphicsLayerRead.StartGeneratingGraphics(Nothing, pScreenDisplay, True, True, False)

Dim pTextElement As ITextElement = pFDOGraphicsLayerRead.NextGraphic

Do Until pTextElement Is Nothing
      Dim pFormattedTextSymbol As IFormattedTextSymbol = pTextElement.Symbol
      Dim pTextBackground As ITextBackground = pFormattedTextSymbol.Background

      If TypeOf pTextBackground Is ILineCallout And pTextBackground IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim pLineCallout As ILineCallout = pTextBackground
            Dim pQueryGeometry As ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IQueryGeometry = pLineCallout
            Dim pElement As IElement = pTextElement
            Dim pPointGeometry As IGeometry = pElement.Geometry
            pScreenDisplay.StartDrawing(pScreenDisplay.WindowDC, ScreenDisplay.ActiveCache)
            Dim pPolyline As IPolyline = New Polyline

            pPolyline = pQueryGeometry.GetGeometry(pScreenDisplay.WindowDC, DisplayTransform, pPointGeometry)

            If pPolyline IsNot Nothing Then      
               'At this point the polyline is always nothing***
               MsgBox(pPolyline.Length)
            End If

            pScreenDisplay.FinishDrawing()
        End If
    pTextElement = pFDOGraphicsLayerRead.NextGraphic
Loop
```

Source: http://forums.esri.com/thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=275411

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The leader line geometry of a LineCallout is generated during draw and is not exposed for access/modification.  SimpleLineCallouts allow for custom line geometries.